# Use two sets of devices in fastlane snapshot?

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm using fastlane snapshot for building the screenshots for the App Store. As usual the set of devices is defined in the `./fastlane/Snapfile`. Now I want a different set of screenshots for a website and do not want all the devices, but only one of them.

So far I defined two lanes in `./fastlane/Fastfile` where one `snapshot` overrides the `devices` like so:

```
  desc "Just run snapshot"
  lane :mysnapshot do
    snapshot
  end

  desc "Just run snapshot for one device only"
  lane :mysnapshot2 do
    snapshot(
      devices: ["iPhone 5"]
    )
  end
```

I'm fine with this, but is there a solution only using the `Snapfile` or using two snapfiles?

(Can I specify the `Snapfile` to use with the `snapfile` command? - From what I see, this is not possible.)

---

Regarding the "underlying problem":

So far I have two targets for UITests. One for the UI tests and one for the screenshots. To run the screenshot UI tests, I created a second scheme which only runs that target. To make the other set of screenshots for the website, I intend to pass information with `launch_arguments`. Depending on those, one or the other set of tests will be run in the screenshots target. Does that sound reasonable or is there a much better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify multiple snapfiles, but you can pass lists of devices via the --devices flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the `--devices` flag, but had problems getting it to work. There is an issue on github regarding such things in fastlane_core. Maybe I did not yet have that version installed which fixes that. On the other hand I'd like to not specify such things on the command line. The details should be fixed in a snapfile or fastfile.

Comment: @RainerSchwarze Can you cross-post this on GitHub? I'll flag it as a feature request. Thanks!

Comment: This would go into the fastlane/snapshot issues list?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.

Comment: Added issue at https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot/issues/376 . I thought I need to add a question tag (I remember reading that somewhere), but it doesn't seem to be possible right now. Let me know, if I need to change anything.